# Docker Descktop 2.3.2.1 - Falha na instalação - Windows 10

Tags: docker

Quando tento instalar o Docker descktop no windows 10 e ocorre este erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Failed to start service: O serviço não respondeu à requisição de início ou controle em tempo hábil
em CommunityInstaller.Service.Service.d__4.MoveNext()
--- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada ---
em System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
em CommunityInstaller.Service.Manager.d__7.MoveNext()
--- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada ---
em System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
em CommunityInstaller.ServiceAction.d__36.MoveNext()
--- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada ---
em System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
em CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.d__32.MoveNext()
--- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada ---
em System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
em CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.d__27.MoveNext()

Answer (score 0):

Também tive esse problema e para corrigir tive que ir no **msconfig** e na aba serviços eu desabilitei o processo "Ligar/Desligar" reiniciei o computador e fiz a instalação do **docker**. Finalizando a instalação, fui novamente no **msconfig** reativei o processo e reiniciei outra vez o computador.

[image: msconfig]

Comment: Funcioou, muito obrigado!